# Read file to bytes in Node using Express

Tags: node.js, file, express

On a web-application that I am working on, users can upload a PDF file. I would like to read this PDF file to a buffer of bytes, which I can pass on to my database to save it as a BLOB. I am doing this in Node, using the Express framework.

Currently, I have the following:

**Upload form:**

```
<form id='uploadForm' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='form-inline'>
            <label for='file'>File:</label>
            <input type='file' name='file'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- some other fields --->
</form>
```

**Server side:**

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var file = req.files.file;
    var path = file.path;
    var fsiz = file.size;
    var buffer = new Buffer(fsiz);

    fs.read(file, buffer, 0, fsiz, 0, function (err, bytesRead, buffer) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(bytesRead);
        console.log(buffer);
    });

});
```

This gives me a `Bad argument` error on the `fs.read` function call. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

[`fs.read()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)'s first argument is supposed to be a file descriptor object, as returned by [`fs.open()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).

You can either first call `fs.open()`, or else use [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback), which takes a path:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var file = req.files.file;
    var path = file.path;
    var fsiz = file.size;
    var buffer = new Buffer(fsiz);

    fs.open(path, 'r', function(err, fd) {

        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, fsiz, 0, function (err, bytesRead, buffer) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(bytesRead);
            console.log(buffer);
        });

    });

});
```

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var file = req.files.file;
    var path = file.path;
    var fsiz = file.size;
    var buffer = new Buffer(fsiz);

    fs.readFile(path, function (err, data) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Comment: But the OP wants to save files **to** the filesystem, not read from it.

Comment: No, he wants to get it as a **Buffer**, and write *that* to a *database*.

Comment: I believe the server side code example clearly demonstrates the OP's intention, especially this line: `var file = req.files.file`. The file comes directly from the user - there is no mention of storing this file on the fs first and then reading it.

Comment: @RobertRossmann And since the file can't just float around, it *does* get saved to the filesystem, in temporary storage. See http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#req.files for how `req.files` works.

Comment: You are right. [this](http://www.hacksparrow.com/handle-file-uploads-in-express-node-js.html) helped me understand. Previously, I used body parsers that did not save the files to the disk but rather provided me with a readable stream that I had to consume in my route. `bodyParser` seems to work differently.

Comment: @Scimonster Is there any way to read an entire file as bytes or hex characters? This question and the documentation (of ExpressJS and NodeJS) don't have a way to parse an entire file thru a JS or TS script.